# Badge Icon Positioned At Bottom Right Of TextView Length Android

Tags: android

I am trying to put a badge at the end of the text in `textview` but when i run the sample on my device, the badge is wrap to `textview` size. I want it bottom right of `textview` length.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/socialbible.reef"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/one_dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="60"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txNumber"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/six_dp"
            android:text="1111111111111111" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txCommentaires"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/six_dp"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/six_dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txCommentaires"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/myButton"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"
    android:text="10"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: for two or more rows txCommentaires becomes invisible.

Comment: Can you post the image you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it work.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/socialbible.reef"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text="60"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txNumber"

            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingBottom="6dp"
            android:text="1111111111111111gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txCommentaires"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:text="10"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```